# Editing Django Formsets

Tags: python, django, forms, formset, formsets

I am very new to Django with limited Python experience.  I am trying to edit a Form and a Formset.  I can edit and save the Form, however I can't get the edits in the Formset to save.  Here is my code from Views:

```
@login_required
def edit_asr(request, asr_id):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if not is_editor(request):
        return HttpResponse("You are not authorized to view this record")

    if request.method == 'POST':

        asr_record = ASR.objects.get(id=asr_id)
        form = BuildASRForm(request.POST, instance=asr_record)
    formset = ASRTripLegFormset(request.POST, instance=asr_record)

    if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            logger.info("ASR %s was edited by %s" % (asr_id, request.user))


            return HttpResponseRedirect('/asr/%s/' % asr_id)

        else:
            logger.error("Edit ASR form returned the following errors for user %s: %s" % (request.user, form.errors))


    else:
        asr_record = ASR.objects.get(id=asr_id)
        form = BuildASRForm(instance=asr_record)
    formset = ASRTripLegFormset(instance=asr_record)
    return render_to_response('asr/edit_asr.html', {'form': form, 'formset': formset, 'asr_id':asr_id}, context)
```

I've tried `if formset.is_valid():` calls indented under the `if form-is_valid():` statement and it throws the `MultiValueDictKeyError` error.  Sorry if this is a novice question, I'm stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: don't you need to call `save()` on your formset for that?

Comment: I'v tried to reformat your code so its indented correctly, but you might want to double check it.

Comment: Do I need to make a if formset.is_valid() call to add the formset.save()?